# ExecuteNonQuery is throwing exception Invalid use of default parameter

Tags: vb.net

When i am passing Nothing as a parameter in vb.net that time ExecuteNonQuery is throwing exception. It is not allowing me to insert null values

Dim id = Nothing
Dim sqlStr = "insert into student where Id =?"

cmd.Parameters.AddawithValue("?",id)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Try ````DBNull.Value```` when you want to pass in a NULL paramater

Comment: And make sure the parameter name matches the query.  ````@id```` would be a good name to use.  ````cmd.Parameters.AddawithValue("@id",id)````  and then make sure your query uses the parameter.

Comment: Don't use AddWithValue at all but especially if you want to insert NULLS. Call Add, specify the data type and then set the Value property, assigning DBNull.Value for NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a bit of nonsense, given that an `INSERT` statement doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. The principle stands though:

```vb
Dim id As Integer?
Dim sql = "UPDATE Student SET Name = @Name WHERE Id = @Id"
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name
    .Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = If(id.HasValue, id.Value, CObj(DBNull.Value))
End With
```